# Codename One - Can't fix CheckBox style

Tags: styles, codenameone

I used the "flat blue" theme on my app and when I tried it on the phone, the checkboxes looked diferent.
I checked every Style Status and the one that matches the phone style is the "disabled" style, although my checkboxes are not disabled.

Thinking I was making a mistake, I edited the "disabled style" to make it look like the "unselected style" but it still looks bad.

What do you think?

[image: Look on device]
[image: Simulator look]

Answer (score 0):

I see an issue there. Its related to recent changes we added for icon fonts where we migrated the old check and radio button icons to use font icons: http://www.codenameone.com/blog/material-icons-background-music-geofencing-gradle.html

This should be fixed in the next server update.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know if you already did that, but now it looks good. :)

Comment: any update? I couldn't still find the option to customize checkbox.

Comment: This specific issue was fixed in 2015. Look at the theme constants section in the developer guide on ways to customize the checkbox image